# 413 ошибка при загрузке файлов

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, nginx

Возникает ошибка 413 при попытке загрузить что то более 1мб. Попробовал изменить настройки nginx.conf все равно ошибка остается. Как исправить? Сервер на Ubuntu 20.04 LTS nginx/1.19.9 сайт на python 3.8.
В настройках моего проекта лимиты выше, на локальном сервере все загружалось.

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    client_max_body_size 300M;
    #tcp_nopush     on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Comment: после добавления `client_max_body_size 300M;` перезагружали `nginx -s reload`?

Comment: не перегружал, думал перезагрузки супервизора досточно. Спасибо, все заработало.